# How to get another key value from an array of json?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Lets say I have these arrayed JSON values

```
[{operation_id: 2, operation_name: FAITHFUL BELIEVERS}, 
{operation_id: 3, operation_name: SAMPLE OP}, 
{operation_id: 4, operation_name: SAMPLE OP 2}]
```

Now I will select the operation name 'SAMPLE OP' but I want to display the value of its operation_id. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is a list of maps, so use `where` on the list to filter it by your predicate. Better still, use `firstWhere` as we assume there's just one match.

The match function returns `true` if the operation name member of the map matches.

`firstWhere` returns the first matching map, and you want the operation id member of that map.

```
  final id = list
      .firstWhere((m) => m['operation_name'] == 'SAMPLE OP')['operation_id'];
```